# How do i setup a datalink over a MQTT channel in Yamcs

Tags: java, mqtt

I'm trying to build a Mission Control Tool using Yamcs framework. For the first step, I want to connect the basic Yamcs server to a MQTT server for sending and receiving data. Yamcs offers a datalink interface for connecting to outside the system over a network. I'm using this interface to build my implementation for MQTT connection inside Yamcs. The issue is that how do I direct Yamcs to look at my implementation instead the default one (That connect over UDP). Documentation states that I have to change the YAML file in configuration for this, but that doesn't work either. Has anyone worked with Yamcs previously, can help me ?

I tried changing the class path in YAML file under datalinks to my implementation class. But it still throws error regarding configuration validation

Answer (score 1):

Yamcs developer here. A colleague discovered your question by accident. I think it is better to post it directly on the github Yamcs discussions page
https://github.com/yamcs/yamcs/discussions

The method you tried should be correct; if you post the config file and the error message, we may be able to see why it does not work.

Comment: This should be a comment on the question, not an answer.

Comment: Thanks for directing to GitHub discussion forum, it may help in the future. I found out the problem I was having , it was due to wrong interface implementation.